# Set thumbnail hover span enlarged image position

Tags: html, css, image, image-gallery

I am trying to implement a photo gallery on this page:

http://cosimocode.com/wtnowork.html

```css
.gallerycontainer{
  position: relative;
  /*Add a height attribute and set to largest image's height to prevent overlaying*/
}

.thumbnail img{
  border: 1px solid white;
  margin: 0 5px 5px 0;
}

.thumbnail:hover{
  background-color: transparent;
}

.thumbnail:hover img{
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.thumbnail span{ /*CSS for enlarged image*/
  position: absolute;
  background-color: lightyellow;
  padding: 5px;
  left: -1000px;
  border: 1px dashed gray;
  visibility: hidden;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.thumbnail span img{ /*CSS for enlarged image*/
  border-width: 0;
  padding: 2px;
}

.thumbnail:hover span{ /*CSS for enlarged image*/
  visibility: visible;
  top: 1000px;
  left: 300px; /*position where enlarged image should offset horizontally */
  z-index: auto;
}
```

```html
<div align="center">
  <div class="gallerycontainer">
    <a class="thumbnail" href="#thumb">
      <img src="/images/jjb01a.jpg" title="Huey 'Piano' Smith" width="100px" border="0" />
      <span><img src="/images/jjb01a.jpg" /></span>
    </a>

    <a class="thumbnail" href="#thumb">
      <img src="/images/jjb02.jpg" title="Archibald" width="100px" border="0" />
      <span><img src="/images/jjb02.jpg" /></span>
    </a>

    <a class="thumbnail" href="#thumb">
      <img src="/images/jjb03.jpg" title="James LaRocca & John Broven" width="100px" border="0" />
      <span><img src="/images/jjb03.jpg" /></span>
    </a>

    <a class="thumbnail" href="#thumb">
      <img src="/images/jjb04.jpg" title="Cosimo Recording" width="100px" border="0" />
      <span><img src="/images/jjb04.jpg" /></span>
    </a>

    <a class="thumbnail" href="#thumb">
      <img src="/images/jjb05.jpg" title="Cosimo Matassa" width="100px" border="0" />
      <span><img src="/images/jjb05.jpg" /></span>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

etc...

I would like to center the image enlarged by the thumbnail hover within the 660px parent container of the page, rather than give it an absolute top: and left: px position, which seems to somehow over-ride the set container width... does this make sense? Am I missing something very obvious? I've tried changing the z-index, etc. but to no avail.

Any ideas?? Thanks So Much!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to achieve that without setting a specific top and left value to center an image.

You have to add a `position: relative` on the parent container.
Then change the `top` and `left` attribute of `.thumbnail:hover span` to `0`, and also add a `right: 0`. To center your `absolute` positioned div (which is the enlarged image), add `margin: 0 auto`. And lastly set that element's width to `max-content`.

**CSS:**

```css
.gallerycontainer {
  position: relative;
}

.thumbnail:hover span {
    visibility: visible;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: auto;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: max-content;
}
```

Comment: THANK YOU MY FRIEND!! It was the addition of position: absolute; to the hover span that finally did it!

Comment: @RedKelly Don't forget to vote and accept ;)

Comment: @RedKelly Just click the check and up arrow